# Citruspay payment gateway integration with splitpay

Tags: php, payment-gateway, citrus-pay

Can you please help me regarding citrus pay payment gateway to split the payment using PHP?

I have to split the order amount into 2 parts one for the merchant and one for the seller. If it's possible please provide me a demo.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: and what did you try ? where is your code ?

Answer (score 2):

The steps to integrate SplitPay API -

1. User Authentication API
2. Seller API
3. Transaction API
4. Settlement API
5. Transaction release API
6. Payout API
7. Refund

You can read the documentation here - https://developers.citruspay.com/documentation/payment-stack/splitpay/

The cURL APIs can be converted into PHP code. You could use this tool - https://incarnate.github.io/curl-to-php/